# Excluding plots in legend created by for loop with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a chart with three line colors and want to only have labels in the legend for the color as well as the trendline. I have done some searching and found that I should be able to put None in for the label or '_nolegend_' but neither work for me. I have also seen that I could do this using artists in matplotlib but don't really know how to create those artists in the for loop. Any suggestions is appreciated as this presentation is coming soon.

```
for teacher in range(3):
teach = ['c','b','t']
for student in range(1,6):
    std = teach[teacher] + str(student)
    df_att_std = df_att[df_att['Student']==std]
    print(df_att_std)
    styles_lst=['s', '^', 'o', 'x', '*']
    color_lst=['r', 'b', 'y']
    style = styles_lst[student-1]
    color = color_lst[teacher]
    week = df_att_std['Week']
    attitude = df_att_std['Attitude'] + teacher*.1
    var = f'l_{std}'
    if student == 1 and teacher == 0:
        plt.plot(week, attitude, c=color, marker=style, label = "Cheryl", alpha=.85)
    elif student == 1 and teacher == 1:
        plt.plot(week, attitude, c=color, marker=style, label = "Brenda", alpha=.85)
    elif student == 1 and teacher ==2:
        plt.plot(week, attitude, c=color, marker=style, label = "Travis", alpha=.85)
    else:
        plt.plot(week, attitude, c=color, marker=style, label='_nolegend_', alpha=.85)
    plt.plot(week, attitude, c=color, marker=style, alpha=.85)
    # Trendline
    x=df_att['Week']
    y=df_att['Attitude']
    z=numpy.polyfit(numpy.float32(x), numpy.float32(y), 1)
    p=numpy.poly1d(z)
    plt.plot(x,p(x), 'k--', linewidth=2)
yticks=['Somewhat Challenging', 'Neutral', 'Somewhat Positive', 
        'Positive']
plt.title("Teacher Student Relationship")
plt.xlabel('Week Number')
plt.ylabel('Attitude')
plt.yticks(ticks=[2,3,4,5], labels=yticks, rotation=30)
plt.xticks(ticks=[1,2,3,4,5])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: The Plot I am getting out]

Comment: It would be `"_nolegend"` (mind the underscore).

Comment: I have tried \_nolegend_ i just did not put the backslash in my post. Fixed now. Yet both None and '\_nolegend_' should do it and they are not

Comment: What I mean is you should put `label="_nolegend"` in every `plot` command you don't want to have appear in the legend. If it doesn't work, show the code where you have attempted to do so.

Comment: Edited the post to include the '\_nolegend_'

Comment: There are still two `plot` commands without it.

Comment: There are three and those I want to be included in the legend. That way I get one plot of each color in the legend

Comment: The truth is, there are 6 !

Comment: Thank for for pointing that out. Sometime working alone it is hard to find your mistakes but you got me there. It is in the plot outside of the loop. Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

The error was that there was a plot outside of the if statement that was reploting all of the lines. Thank you to ImportanceOfBeingEarnist for looking this over.